# Javascript Web Application Testing

Tags: javascript, frontend

As I develop more complicated applications, I'm spending a lot of time doing functional testing.

But... I'm constantly hindered by having to enter the same information over and over again into form fields etc. to get to the second / third / fourth stage of a javascript process.

There must be an easier, more efficient and better way of doing this - how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] functional testing [...]

Do you do the functional testing by hand?

There are many ways to test this programatically:

- https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/
- https://www.cypress.io/
- and a bazillion more (see this article: https://medium.com/welldone-software/an-overview-of-javascript-testing-in-2019-264e19514d0a)